# C# Won't change lines in a text file

Tags: c#, text, pastebin

Okay, believe me, I have researched EVERYWHERE and asked a few friends about this problem. But my code: http://pastebin.com/0JSA9MzA in there. The code between the two lines specified is supposed to check a text document line by line for the line of text specified by the startLine variable, it is then supposed to change everything from the oldFont variable to the newFont variable, and then end at the endLine variable. But whenever I run it, it fails to produce results, and doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Please get the relevant parts of the code and embed them into your question.

Comment: -1: please do inline code that is the problem instead of providing a link. No need for "searched everywhere" comments.

Answer (score 2):

Well your code won't change the text in the file unless you tell it to change the text in the file. You are currently only modifying the text that you read in, but you're never writing it back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   private void editText()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader read = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);

        //write to new file because it's not possible to replace text in existing file directly
        System.IO.TextWriter writer = new System.IO.TextWriter(filePath+"_"); 

        while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line); //write unmodified line to new file

            if (startLine == line)
            {
                while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line == endLine)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(line); //write unmodified line to new file
                        break;  //exit cycle
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(oldFont, newFontS); //replace content in line
                        writer.WriteLine(line); //write modified line to new file
                    }                       
                }
            }
        }

        read.Close();
        writer.Close(); 

        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); //delete old file
        System.IO.File.Move(filePath+"_",filePath); //rename new file to original filename            


        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
```

Comment: It isn't working, because TextWriter can't be used like that, so I switched it out with StreamWriter, and it will not work.